# "Colspan" atribute not working for "td" tag with BlazorContextMenu thead

Tags: c#, html, frontend, blazor

I am working with Blazor project and have some tables. Tag 'thead' is set by BlazorContextMenu and got definition of that tag. Also I want to set one row as something like header for group of other rows below him. So I set attribute "colspan" to length of the table, but it's not affected by it. BlazorContextMenu source: https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu

Definition of the thead:

```
<ContextMenuTrigger WrapperTag="thead" CssClass="my-class">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</ContextMenuTrigger>
```

And the content I want to be for the full length of the row:

```
<tr class="title-row">
    <td colspan="3">
        <h2>
            Name of the row
        </h2>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Borehead, thank you for help.

Comment: This should work as regular HTML, what does the generated HTML look like on your page?

Comment: Thank you for the responce. The generated HTML looks like tag specified at attribute WrapperTag="thead", so that is like just "thead" with "tr" and "th" in it, but I guess that the problem is with Blazor context menu

Comment: [Polite] `ContextMenuTrigger` is not part of any standard Blazor component I know.  You need to state in your question what component you are using.  We are not mind readers!  Is this a DevExpress component? or this - https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu. Or what?

Comment: Thank you for the remark, I've edited the question to fix that. Yes, the source is [BlazorContextMenu at github](https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to cover row by empty context menu:

```
<ContextMenuTrigger WrapperTag="tr" MenuId="none">
    <td colspan="3">
        <h2>
            Name of the row
        </h2>
    </td>
<ContextMenuTriger/>
```

But I guess that is not quite the best practice, so I am still looking for better solutions